Why are laser beams not affected by gravitational waves in Michelson interferometer?
Michelson interferometers are used to detect gravitational waves. This means two laser beams are sent in long arms and reflected at the end. Usually, they annihilate each other and no signal is detected. If gravitational waves alters space time, the way of the two laser beams is altered (shortened or prolonged) and the two reflected beams no longer annihilate each other.
Why does the gravitational wave alter space (shorter or longer) and does not affect light in the same way? In other words, how do we know that a gravitational wave affecting one arm more then the other leads to different signal propagation times?

IIRC the round-trip propagation time in the presence of a gravitational wave is derived in one of the more recent editions of Schutz's A First Course in General Relativity.  So if seeing a calculation of this effect would answer your question sufficiently, check that book out.
